# Can I use Django truncatewords filter without image fields?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-template-filters, django-3.1

I upload a photo with ckeditor on my blog and show this photo in the content area. To show the summary of a blog on the home page, I limit the content area to `truncatewords`, but if there is an image within the word limits I specified, this image is shown in the blog summary. How do I prevent this situation? How can I prevent images from appearing when using the `truncatewords` filter?

```
{{ blog.content|safe|truncatewords:50 }}
```